# how to openssl_decrypt in android?

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have code `$value = openssl_encrypt($value, "AES-258", "123456789012acsdzxcsdweasd", 0, $123456789012345);` in my PHP. And then the $value pass using json_encoded.

And now, i want to decrypt that $value in android using openssl_decrypt but no one build the libary for it. how to do that in simple way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

```
public class DecryptUtils{
    public static String AES ( byte [] cipherText, String encryptionKey ) 
        {
            String decrypted = null;

            try
            {
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance ( "AES");
                SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec ( encryptionKey.getBytes ( "UTF-8" ), "AES" );
                cipher.init ( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
                decrypted = new String ( cipher.doFinal ( cipherText ), "UTF-8" );a
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            return decrypted;
        }
}
```